# View.GONE still taking space in the layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, visibility

I want to set a view to GONE and then have the remaining space taken up by the other views.

Right now if i set it to GONE it leaves a space where it used to be in the layout, the view is a viewpager with fixed height.

So far ive read i have to remove the margins, and not have a fixed height for the viewpager so ive tried doing something like this

```
    if (cardsChoice.predictive == true) {

        viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(8,4,8,0);
        layoutParams.height = R.dimen.predicts_pager_height;
        viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }else{

        viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        layoutParams.height = 0;
        viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

However this doesnt work - the view seems to either ignore the values and matches the parent or disappears and takes the rest of the layout out with it.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerHolder"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_pager_height" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_predicts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/predicts_pager_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewpager2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewpager_predicts"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_white_24dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewpager2" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put visibility:gone parameter in the xml file and see how things behave. I don't think the margins have anything to do here, but maybe the fact, that some items require that view because they are aligned as layout_below:viewpager_predicts

Comment: make it View.INVISIBLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mentioned that  "have the remaining space taken up by the other views " , which other views. I can see following

viewpager2 - it will not take the space because it has fixed height card_pager_height
viewpager -  will take up the space only  if tabs is affacted because of viewpager_predicts.

tabs - must be affected after viewpager_predicts is gone, but you have defined `android:layout_below="@id/viewpager_predicts"` which will not remain valid after viewpager_predicts is gone. 
Please correct it.

one more thing after you set visibility to GONE, no need to change layoutParam, as it will be of no use.

Comment: thank you very much all of what you said makes perfect sense and I'm sure will help I'm going to try some things see if i can get it working i was hoping for the tab layout to be under viewpager2 unless boolean was equal to x in which case would be under viewpagerpredicts,  I'm self taught and don't read the docs as much as maybe i should, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. May be layout_marginTop="64dp" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" confusing you.
2. Possible reason could be fragment get attached to host activity.
   set Pager adapter null then set visibility gone.

   if (cardsChoice.predictive == true) {
           viewPagerPredicts.setAdapter(new YourFragmentAdapter());

   ```
       viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
       (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
       layoutParams.setMargins(8,4,8,0);
       layoutParams.height = R.dimen.predicts_pager_height;
       viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   }else{

       viewPagerPredicts.setAdapter(null);
       viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  
       (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
       layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
       layoutParams.height = 0;
       viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
   }
   ```

Comment: This looks like a good idea I'll check it out tonight and update here many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like this.
Put it into some layout file and check behavior on the preview. Set visibility gone on the second textview and you will notice that first text view took remaining screen height. This can be achieved directly from layout without necessity to setting up things programmatically.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/about_app" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/about_app" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok ive fixed my issue partly it was due to my layout as pointed out by @Girish (nothing was taking up the empty space as there was nothing that could) also i was trying to edit layout params after the layout was GONE but another thing i want to mention is that i am using a dimens for my layout height and this seems to also result in the space being empty but holding its space (acting like View.INVISIBLE) so to get around this i've wrapped it in another view and made that View.GONE which seems to work great so my final code looks like this

```
if (cardsChoice.predictive) {

        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(8,4,8,0);
        viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }else{

        viewPagerPredicts.setAdapter(null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)viewPagerPredicts.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        viewPagerPredicts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        viewPagerPredicts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

and my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerHolder"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_pager_height" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/predictsHolder"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_predicts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/predicts_pager_height" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />


    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_white_24dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

thanks for the help you both deserve a cookie and the points for the answer but i can only except one sorry